# How to iterate over a dataframe with criteria and plot the results?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a df that has data over the last 6 months. I want to split this up into 7 unique dataframes, each one housing the data on a given day. Monday, Tuesday, etc. I already have a column called "weekday" to help with this.

Here's the data I'm working with:

```
+---+------------+----------+-----------+------------+
|   |    Date    | Activity |  Weekday  |   Hours    |
+---+------------+----------+-----------+------------+
| 0 | 2020-06-01 | Gen Ab   | Monday    | 347.250000 |
| 1 | 2020-06-02 | Gen Ab   | Tuesday   | 286.266667 |
| 2 | 2020-06-03 | Gen Ab   | Wednesday | 169.583333 |
| 3 | 2020-06-04 | Gen Ab   | Thursday  | 312.633333 |
| 4 | 2020-06-05 | Gen Ab   | Friday    | 317.566667 |
| 5 | 2020-06-08 | Gen Ab   | Monday    | 285.800000 |
| 6 | 2020-06-09 | Gen Ab   | Tuesday   | 213.166667 |
+---+------------+----------+-----------+------------+
```

This code doesn't work, but it's what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
day = grouped['Weekday'].unique()

for day in day:
    f"df_{str(day)}" = grouped.loc[(grouped['Activity'] == 'Gen Ab')
    & (grouped['Weekday'].isin([f'{day}']))].reset_index(drop=True)
```

The formatted string would be the name of the new df. So "df_Monday", "df_Tuesday", etc.

.isin also uses a formatted string since I'm filtering for every day.

Finally, I want to plot each of the dataframes into a line graph so we can see the data of each day over time.

I'm sure there's a better way to plot the data (my end goal) but I would also like to know how to do this loop here in case I want to use something similar in the future.

Can anyone help with both these things?

Comment: why do you want 7 different dataframe? what happens next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better using a dictionary for this task, like:

```py
days = grouped['Weekday'].unique()

wday = {day: grouped.loc[(grouped['Activity'] == 'Gen Ab') & (grouped['Weekday']==day)]\
         .reset_index(drop=True) for day in days}
```

where you can access a week day with `wday['Monday']`.

---

That said, if you really want to create variables like that, you can use [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) (with caution!):

```
days = grouped['Weekday'].unique()

for day in days:
    df = grouped.loc[(grouped['Activity'] == 'Gen Ab') & (grouped['Weekday']==day)]\
    .reset_index(drop=True)
    exec(f'df_{day} = df')
```

where you can access Monday data with `df_Monday`.

---

Since @BigBen already showed you how to plot in loop using `matplotlib`, you may also consider plotting the data directly by using `seaborn`, then customizing with `matplotlib`:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Convert date to datetime to make sure it'll ordered properly
grouped.Date = grouped.Date.astype('datetime64[ns]')

# Make plot
sns.lineplot(data=grouped, x='Date', y='Hours', hue='Weekday')
# Customize plot
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

The labels will be ordered as they appeared in data (it's correclty ordered in your example). If you want to force a specific order, then convert `Weekday` column to `Categorical` before ploting:

```py
grouped.Weekday = pd.Categorical(grouped.Weekday, categories=['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'])
```

Comment: Upvote for the suggestion of seaborn. I thought about this... but then wasn't sure what OP wanted on the x-axis (whether date or not).

Comment: I had upvoted your answer as well. You got right to the point of the OP question by using loop to plot the variables (or dataframes).

Comment: @BigBen I wanted the date by month but I was so caught up in trying to figure this out I forgot to mention it. Thank you for your answer as well! I suck at matplotlib

Comment: @Mofongo - got it. I edited my answer accordingly. This should definitely still be the accepted answer as it is more thorough, plus seaborn is probably easier here than pure matplotlib.

Comment: @BigBen Awesome, I just got back to working on this so that's a big help. Also, thank you for the clarity. I didn't know which to mark as correct.

Answer (score 2):

If your end goal is just to plot, perhaps something like this (resulting plot can definitely be prettified):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

...

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for day in df['Weekday'].unique():
    temp_df = df[(df['Weekday'] == day) & (df['Activity'] == 'Gen Ab')]
    ax.plot('Date', 'Hours', data=temp_df, label=day)
    
ax.legend(loc='upper right')
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

Sample Output:

[image]